# MySQL Datetime displays 0:00:00

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run a query to display a datetime in MySQL, the time displayed is sometimes 0:00:00, even though when I query for the hour, minute, or second, I get the values I would expect.

[image: datetime query and response]

As you can see, the stored time is 9:24:23, but the displayed time is 0:00:00.

The column datetime has a data type datetime. Is there a way to get my queries to display the correct time without doing a terrible concat(hour,minute,second) workaround?

EDIT:
Sometimes, I get the datetime as expected, and I don't see any difference between the times that display and those that don't.

[image]

Here's the table setup:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a setting on whatever client you are using.

Comment: are both of those results from the same session & user & database?  Could you query the same postID?

Comment: Could you `DESC` the table?

Comment: Yes, I've added a query in which the I got half of the results as expected and half that were malformed.

Comment: put datetime in backticks?  maybe use of the the reserved/keword as a column name is causing an issue.  yes this is very odd, and your example of both on same SQL is nothing short of amazingly odd.  ***Note it's not just time it's the month and day that are also 00-00*** in the dual result entry.

Comment: Tried backticks, no luck.

Comment: @Ealau What are the data sources for this table?

Comment: I'm at a loss other than to format the data as Gordon Linoff suggested.   I was hoping it would be a setting based on user; but the mixed results seem to indicate it's data; but the functions prove it's not.  my next stop would be to dump the data; drop the table recreate the table and reload the data.  But that can't be it or you'd have a problem with the function calls; so that leads me to a bad UI.  If you select using a different application/Tool  does it work?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's bad UI - I'm just using MySQL Shell, but when I use the workbench, I can see the dates as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This would appear to be a problem in user interface.  One solution is to format the value as a string:

```
select date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

This should print correctly.